# I want to put PHP condition for update column on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to put PHP condition If "Credit" Column updated then update "PlayerPower" Column on MySQL Table as well.

and This is my code , I put a condition that If "Credit" column is less than 5  then gives error : "Your Credit is not Enough , Please Buy a Credit" , If else then update "Credit" column. My issue is for update "PlayerPower" with condition Column. Please guide me how is it possible ?

```
<?php

    if (session_id() == "")
    {
       session_start();
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
       $accessdenied_page = '';
       header('Location: '.$accessdenied_page);
       exit;
    }

    $dbservername = 'localhost';
    $dbusername = '******';
    $dbpassword = '******';
    $dbname = '******';
    $dbtable = '******';
    $success_page = '/page5.php';
    $wusername = $_SESSION['username'];

    $conn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT `Credit` FROM `".$dbtable."` WHERE `username` = '$wusername'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($row['Credit'] < 5) {
                echo "Your Credit is not Enough , Please Buy a Credit";
            }    
            else {
               $sql2 = "UPDATE `".$dbtable."` SET `Credit` = `Credit` - 5 WHERE `username` = '$wusername' AND `Credit` >= 5";
               $conn->query($sql2);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
    header('Location: '.$success_page);
    exit;
    ?>
```

Comment: your question is not at all clear

Comment: what value would you like `PlayerPower` to have?

Comment: I put "PlayerPower" in sql and did conn but I removed from my above code. because it didn't work true. In any situation became updated!

Comment: @Ivan86 I want to be "PlayerPower" + 5

Comment: @Ivan86 If "Credit" Column updated then update "PlayerPower" Column

Comment: @Ivan86 I want to be in this style : `$sql3 = "UPDATE `".$dbtable."` SET `Credit` = `Credit` + 5 WHERE `username` = '$wusername'";`

Comment: `UPDATE ".$dbtable." SET Credit = Credit + 5, PlayerPower = 100 ...`

Comment: there is no way SQL will execute PHP. The way is PHP generate SQL query.

Comment: @Alex "PlayerPower" is a separate Column . how you put it with "Credit" Column ?!

Comment: @Ashkan what do you mean **how?** using  coma :-)

Comment: You SET "Credit" column , how it can work for "PlayerPower" Column?!

Comment: if you don't want to change Credit   - remove it from query `UPDATE ".$dbtable." SET PlayerPower = 100 ...`

Comment: I understood now , thank you so much @Alex

Comment: @Alex Please Check my above code , I edited it now , But why in any situation "PlayerPower" updated?! I want just If the "Credit" updated , the "PlayerPower" become update as well!

Comment: you should not change your post with good code. It makes no sense for future visitors to undertstand your QUESTION and solutions provided. So please keep original code. SO is not for only help you. But to help other people when they meet same problems as you do.

Comment: Okay @Alex I edited my above code just for now till you can see my problem , after the issue solved i will put it in first originial style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With comments about `sql injection` aside could you not alter the initial select query to test for credit greater than 5 - if the recordset is empty then the user does not have credit - otherwise update.

```
$sql = "select `credit` from `".$dbtable."` 
            where `username` = '$wusername' and `credit` >= 5";
$result = $conn->query( $sql );

if ( $result->num_rows == 1 ) {

    $sql="update `".$dbtable."` set `credit` = `credit` - 5, `playerpower` = `playerpower` + 5 where `username` = '$wusername' ";

    $result = $conn->query( $sql );
    exit( header('Location: '.$success_page ) );
} else {
    echo "You do not have enough credit! Please buy credits";
}
```

Comment: There was a missing semi-colon from the echo statement

Comment: I tested your code , It works true , Thanks you so much

Comment: Glad it's working - though please take a look at using prepared statements. This might be of interest http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

```
        if ($row['Credit'] < 5) {
            echo "Your Credit is not Enough , Please Buy a Credit";
        }    
        else {
           $sql2 = "UPDATE `".$dbtable."` SET `Credit` = `Credit` - 5, PlayerPower = 100 WHERE `username` = '$wusername' AND `Credit` >= 5";
           $conn->query($sql2);
        }
```

**EDIT 1** Whatever you want to check - check. Ше is up to you now. Since you already checked if `credit < 5` that means you will never call this `UPDATE` query when `credit = 0` because **0 < 5**

Comment: Please Check my above code , I edited it now , But why in any situation "PlayerPower" updated?! I want just If the "Credit" updated , the "PlayerPower" become update as well!

Comment: Whenever the "Credit" is 0 I don't want the "PlayerPower" become update!

Comment: then how will be for "PlayerPower" ? I want whenever the "Credit" of the clients became less than "5" their "PlayerPower" do not become update.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

$sql2 = "UPDATE `".$dbtable."` SET Credit = Credit - 5, PlayerPower = PlayerPower +5;

You can avoid the redundant code:  WHERE `username` = '$wusername' AND `Credit` >= 5";

Questions to Ashkan:  Please correct my understanding. So if Credit is > 5 then you want to update the Credit column in the table by 'Credit' - 5? and PowerPlayer by PowerPlayer + 5

Comment: Ashkan, if you are satisfied with my answer can you please upvote the same?

Comment: Please Check my above code , I edited it now , But why in any situation "PlayerPower" updated?! I want just If the "Credit" updated , the "PlayerPower" become update as well!

Comment: Whenever the "Credit" is 0 I don't want the "PlayerPower" become update!

Comment: @Ann Ashkan can't upvote yet, 15 reputation points are needed for upvote privilige.